# Union has no member named 'B'

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, unions

I have a `union` with a `struct` inside. When trying to compile on Linux, I get an error (or more like 50 of the same kind). The same code works in Visual Studio on Windows.

> main.c:772:43: error: ‘union data’ has no member named ‘B’
> fwrite(&u.B, sizeof(char), sizeof(u.B), out);
> ^

I declare all my structs in a header file, "typedefs.h":

```
union data {
    short buf;
    struct D {
        char A;
        char B;
    };
};
```

What could be the issue and possible fix?

Comment: you didn't name the field for `D`

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm fairly new to C, how do i do that?

Comment: Move the D after the brackets and use u.D.B

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous structures are allowed as nested members of other structures or unions in Standard C **but they can't have a tag**. From [this Draft C11 Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> ##### 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> …
> 13     An unnamed member whose type specifier is a
> structure specifier with no tag is called an anonymous structure; an
> unnamed member whose type specifier is a union specifier with no tag
> is called an anonymous union. The members of an anonymous structure or
> union are considered to be members of the containing structure or
> union. This applies recursively if the containing structure or union
> is also anonymous.

However, in your code, although the nested structure doesn't have a name, it *does* have a tag (the `D`); so, in formal terms, it cannot be used as an anonymous structure and must be given a name. From the same section of the Standard cited above:

> 2    A struct-declaration that does not declare an anonymous
> structure or anonymous union shall contain a struct-declarator-list.

However, the MSVC (Visual Studio) compiler accepts unnamed ('anonymous') structures that have a tag, as an extension.

So, to use the code in your `write` call as-is, and to keep it Standard-conformant, you need to remove the `D` tag from your inner structure:

```cpp
union data {
    short buf;
    struct {
        char A;
        char B;
    };
};
```

Note that the clang-cl compiler (a version of clang that can be used within Visual Studio) gives a warning for your version of the code (though not especially helpful unless you can parse the final, `[-Wmicrosoft-anon-tag]` part):

> warning : anonymous structs are a Microsoft extension
> [-Wmicrosoft-anon-tag]

Comment: The paragraph you cite, 6.7.2.1 13, does not say anonymous structures are not allowed so long as they do not have a tag. It says that if an unnamed structure (or union) member does not have a tag, then it is an anonymous structure (or union). The paragraph that addresses a declaration inside a structure (or union) declaration that does not name a member is 6.7.2.1 2: “A struct-declaration that does not declare an anonymous structure or anonymous union shall contain a struct-declarator-list.”…

Comment: … A struct-declaration is any declaration inside a structure (or union), not just a declaration of a structure or union. So 6.7.2.1 2 (which is a constraint) says you cannot have `int;` inside a structure definition, as well as that you cannot have `struct foo { stuff };`.

Comment: @Eric Edited. But it's late, where I am, and my standardese-parsing skills may not be at their best.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared a struct type inside of a union, but not an instance of a struct.  If you remove the tag name from the struct, you'll define an instance of an anonymous struct inside of the union.  This will also make the struct members look like members of the union.

```
union data {
    short buf;
    struct {
        char A;
        char B;
    };
};
```